# convergence in distribution of sum of two normals

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, convergence

Let $x_n, y_n$ be sequences of zero mean random variables, not necessarily i.i.d. 
Suppose that there are finite $\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2$ such that
$$x_n\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma_1^2), $$ and
$$y_n\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma_2^2). $$
Can I say that $x_n+y_n{\to} N(0,\sigma^2)$ for some finite $\sigma^2$?

I know that I can't describe $\sigma_2$, but the limiting distribution of $x_n+y_n$ is still normally distributed?

Comment: Are $x_n$ and  $y_n$ independent?

Comment: no. it is not needed

Comment: Please add that as an edit to the question. Not everybody reads comments.

Comment: You can _say_ it if you like but whether it is a true statement or not is a different matter. The sum of two normal random variables is _not_ a normal random variable unless the variables are _jointly_ normal (which joint normality would hold for independent random variables but you have ruled it out).

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes. I perceived that the limiting distribution of $x_n+y_n$ need not to be Gaussian.

Comment: In an extreme case, take $y_n = -x_n$.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3684452/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom is there any problem about it? I believe that there are people there that are not in this community. So I decided to post on both.

Comment: Yes it is discouraged.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I'm fine posting on both communities unless one show me  that it is prohibited.

Comment: Check the meta pages on both sites if you need convincing. I highlighted the site policy. You are of course free to do what you wish. Please don't extend this comment thread unnecessarily.

Comment: @StubbornAtom It is not prohibited. Next time I will taylor my question to each community to avoid people to bother me again, unnecessarily.

Comment: What 'bother'? Cross-posting happens all the time and usually someone points it out if detected (which is all I did); there is nothing to be agitated about this. Of course no one is going to prohibit you; it is just discouraged in general (more so if you do this without cross-linking) as I mentioned in a previous comment. Cf. https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2131/119261, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9337/321264.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even in the special case where $X_n \sim N(0,\sigma_{1,n}^2), Y_n \sim N(0,\sigma_{2,n}^2)$ where $\{\sigma_{1,n}^2\}$ and $\{\sigma_{2,n}^2\}$ are sequences of positive real numbers converging to $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ respectively, and so $X_n \overset{d}{\to}N(0,\sigma_{1}^2), Y_n \overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma_{2}^2)$, it is not possible to assert that $X_n+Y_n$ is a normal random variable of any kind or that $X_n+Y_n$ converges in distribution to a normal random variable unless it is also asserted that $X_n, Y_n$ are *jointly* normal (which implies that $X_n, Y_n$ are also individually (marginally) normal random variables).  If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are indeed jointly normal with correlation coefficient $\rho_n$ where $\lim_{n\to\infty} \rho_n = \rho$, then 
$$X_n+Y_n \overset{d}{\to}N(0,\sigma_{1}^2 + \sigma_{2}^2 + 2\rho \sigma_{1}\sigma_{2})$$